# DAX Dynamodb context deadline exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

My service uses AWS dynamodb with DAX, under high load my requests are failing with this error-

"error":"RequestCanceled: request context canceled
caused by: context deadline exceeded

Any idea on what this error can be attributed to?

Comment: Does anyone have a workaround for this problem?

Comment: What does your DAX cluster look like?